# meta open graph для главной

Tags: html, meta

Здравствуйте.
Скажите, вот добавляю теги Opengraph к главной странице сайта index.php, чтоб в том же Вконтакте сделать красивую ссылку

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Мой сайт">
<meta property="og:title" content="Мой сайт">
<meta property="og:description" content="описание">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://сайт.ru/">
<meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU">
```

и получается что при адресе сайт.ru у меня эти теги не отображаются, а при адресе сайт.ru/index.php отображаются. Как можно сделать так, чтобы тэги и просто по аресу сайт.ru отображались

Comment: Это единственное отличие *сайт.ru/index.php* и *сайт.ru*? Как код вставляете?

Comment: да, единственное

Comment: а в подключении этого куска кода нет никаких условий?

Comment: Вот та-же беда на старом сайте, там просто голый HTML, поэтому та-же проблема, пробовал поиграть с .htaccess но без особого толку.